# In what scenarios will I use `netsh http add urlacl`?

Tags: cmd.exe, window, netsh

I'm trying to understand in which scenarious I will need to use such command  :

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://server1:1234/ user=Everyone
```

Is it like using the `hosts` file where I can connect a specific address to my computer ? (I don't think so).

The [*docs*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490939.aspx) are not that clear ( to me) :

> Netsh is a command-line scripting utility that allows you to, either
>   locally or remotely, display or modify the network configuration of a
>   computer that is currently running. Netsh also provides a scripting
>   feature that allows you to run a group of commands in batch mode
>   against a specified computer. Netsh can also save a configuration
>   script in a text file for archival purposes or to help you configure
>   other servers.

**Question:**

Can someone please supply a real life scenario (+ implementation) where I will want to use it ?

**Additional Info :**
I've read [*this question*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564669/net-httplistener-prefix-issue-with-anything-other-than-localhost) where a guy who've tried to access ( via C#) to :

`http://localhost:1234` works, but

`http://server1:1234` fails

(However -  I don't understand why didn't he use the `hosts` file which could solve it )  - But then another person has answered that `netsh` will do the job.
So I guess I'm missing something here.

Comment: I perfectly know what hosts file is used for i do it every day for the last 1 years. I dont understand how the code in my question is differ from hosts file. It seems that they both do the same. And sadly , you didnt supply any difference in your answer

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You would use `netsh http` when modifying the configuration of `http.sys`,
which is totally different from the `hosts` file, working on a much lower
level of Windows. This level is the one that handles the running of
an HTTP server *locally in your computer*, so is concerned with requests
coming *into* your computer, rather than the ones going *out* to the Internet.

This is the architecture in Windows for serving URL requests :

[image: http.sys architecture]

`http.sys` is the driver that listens to HTTP traffic and dispatches
requests based on the URL to processes, so multiple processes can listen
to HTTP traffic on the same port.

`http.sys` was introduced in Windows server 2003.
Before, applications just opened a socket on an endpoint (IP:Port),
listening to incoming traffic and parsing it.
The problem was that this made it impossible for
all the applications to use port 80 (http) and 443 (https),
as with the socket model only one application can listen to an endpoint
at any given time.

When the [Internet Information Services (IIS)](https://www.iis.net/)
Web server, or any application that uses the HTTP Server API, listen on some HTTP request path, they need to register a URL prefix on `http.sys`.
We call this process **registration**.

When an incoming request is picked by `http.sys` and it is delivered to the
the right registered application, this is called **routing**.

Any application running in administrator mode can register for a URL.
A non-administrator application needs to use `netsh http add urlacl`
to receive the request.

Conclusion: Since you are not building a low-level URL server
running in non-administrator mode,
you have no reason to use `netsh http add urlacl`.

References :

- [Configuring HTTP and HTTPS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-http-and-https)
- [Namespace Reservations, Registrations, and Routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364673(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [HTTP.sys web server implementation in ASP.NET Core](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437733/Demystify-http-sys-with-HttpSysManager)
- [Demystify http.sys with HttpSysManager](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437733/Demystify-http-sys-with-HttpSysManager)

Comment: Can you please provide a scenario where something like:" a user wants to connect to your iis with...."

Comment: This is a method for applications to work side-by-side with IIS. If it registers for a URL prefix, the application will get all its requests directly and not through IIS, meaning it needs not be written as an extension of IIS, nor do you even need to install IIS (this is in theory - I don't know how well in practice http.sys is independent from IIS).